# airdrop to 7Z9PiwoCyzE8cnbrturs8Ni4AZHPyekSRN1pkFk4u4bL failed: Internal error

Tags: web3.js

```
    const privateKey = 'REDACTED'
    const secretKey = Buffer.from(privateKey)
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey, {skipValidation: true});
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("testnet"));
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        keypair.publicKey,
        LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
      );
    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
```

I get an error when executing the requestAirdrop function.

```
SolanaJSONRPCError: airdrop to 7Z9PiwoCyzE8cnbrturs8Ni4AZHPyekSRN1pkFk4u4bL failed: Internal error
    at Connection.requestAirdrop (/Users/akira/dea/pmg/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6471:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: -32603,
  data: undefined
}
```

Am I writing some wrong code?

Comment: share your wallet public key.
P.S="NEVER" share your private keys with anyone. Otherwise they can transfer your digital assets into their accounts such as NFTs and SOL balance.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply generate a new wallet and airdrop using the following code:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";

const keypair: anchor.web3.Keypair = await anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    const tx = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(keypair.publicKey, 2 * anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(tx);
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
```

Or alternatively if you want funds in a specific wallet then:

```
const {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  clusterApiUrl,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
} = require("@solana/web3.js");

const pubKey = new PublicKey(ENTER_YOUR_PUBLICKEY_HERE);
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
  const tx = await connection.requestAirdrop(pubKey, 2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
  await connection.confirmTransaction(tx);
```

Comment: also make sure you are on devnet, keypair exists and path is set to the right idl file. You can check it by running ```solana config get``` in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else getting this error. There are some dead nodes in the Solana dev net pool. It's a DNS problem, and they're using GeoDNS to send you to a specific node. If I hit 67.209.54.90, I get that error. If I override devnet to be 139.178.65.155, it works.

Example curl to override:

```
curl -v https://api.devnet.solana.com --resolve api.devnet.solana.com:443:139.178.65.155 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"requestAirdrop", "params":["<wallet pub key>", 1000000000]}'
```

Comment: THis worked for me